# I have cloned a ruby project from gitlab and trying to run but gem is not installing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have cloned the project and also resolved so many issues related to gems installation and other configuration but now i am stuck on this issue

```
RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:87:in `block in materialize': Could not find mini_portile2-2.0.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

I have tried a lot to install this gem but no avail.
when i try to install this gem this message shows

```
$ gem install miniportile --version "2-2.0.0"
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'miniportile' (= 2.pre.2.0.0) in any repository
```

Comment: Just run `bundle install` in the project root directory (which contains the `Gemfile`). It should install all required gems in suitable versions.

Comment: run bundle install and the new error occur
Could not find rake-11.1.2 in any of the sources
I run this command 
$ gem install rake --version "11.1.2"
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rake' (= 11.1.2) in any repository

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line in your gemfile to:

```
gem 'mini_portile2', '~> 2.0.0'
```

Or from the command line:

```
gem install mini_portile2 --version '2.0.0'
```

Comment: ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'mini_portile2' (= 2.0.0) in any repository

Answer (score 0):

https://rubygems.org/gems/mini_portile

choose a valid version of that gem, e.g. 0.6.2 Note the underscore in the gem name:

```
    $ gem install mini_portile --version 0.6.2
```